# How can I access the property of an ellipse inside a group in ActionScript?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, mxml

Let's say I have the following MXML:

```
        <s:Group id="b01">
            <s:Ellipse x="267" y="96" width="30" height="28">
                <s:stroke>
                    <s:SolidColorStroke color="white" weight="1" />
                </s:stroke>
                <s:fill>
                    <s:SolidColor color="#F2FF00" alpha="0.5" />
                </s:fill>
            </s:Ellipse>
        </s:Group>
```

And that I have a dozen more of these groups with different ID's. How can I modify the fill color of each Ellipse using ActionScript? I know I can do something like this:

```
b01.getElementAt(0).width;
```

And that will give me the width of the Ellipse. But how can I access the SolidColorStroke color or the SolidColor fill?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the color you can use:

```as3
SolidColor(Ellipse(b01.getElementAt(0)).fill).color = 0xFF0000;
```

or you can set a `id` to each `s:SolidColor` tag --as you did for `s:Group` tag -- and change its color via `id.color = 0xFF0000;`

```mxml
<s:Group id="b01">
    ...
        <s:fill>
            <s:SolidColor id="f01" color="#F2FF00" alpha="0.5" />
        </s:fill>
    ...
</s:Group>
```

Comment: Thanks! This works :)
Now let's say that I have a `Rect` as well... how can I programatically determine if it is an `Ellipse` or `Rect`?

Comment: I didnt test buy i think you can do via `if (b01.getElementAt(0) is Ellipse)` or `if (b01.getElementAt(0) is Rect)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
(b01.getElementAt(0) as Ellipse).stroke = new SolidColorStroke(...)

(b01.getElementAt(0) as Ellipse).fill = new SolidColor(...)
```